# How to get the extension of a file which is stored in the system using php

Tags: php

I am trying to check whether a file name (user_id) with a particular extension exists in a location. Whenever I execute this only if part gets executed and the control does not goes to the else if part, even though the image is not of the png extension.

```php
$img1 = "../img/profile_imgs/".$user_id.".jpg";
$img2 = "../img/profile_imgs/".$user_id.".png";
$img3 = "../img/profile_imgs/".$user_id.".jpeg";

if (is_bool(file_exists($img1))==1)
{       
    
   echo "am here in jpg";           
   $prof_img =$img_name_jpg;
}
else if (is_bool(file_exists($img2))==1)
{
   echo "am here in png";
   $prof_img =$img_name_png;
}
else if (is_bool(file_exists($img3))==1){
    echo "am here in jpeg";
    $prof_img =$img_name_jpeg;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using is_bool() ?

Comment: `file_exist()` always returns a boolean. You want to test the value of the function, not just whether it's boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use this complicated condition:

```
if (is_bool(file_exists($img1))==1)
```

This should work just fine:

```
$img1 = "../img/profile_imgs/".$user_id.".jpg";
$img2 = "../img/profile_imgs/".$user_id.".png";
$img3 = "../img/profile_imgs/".$user_id.".jpeg";

if (file_exists($img1))
{       
    echo "am here in jpg";
    $prof_img = $img_name_jpg;
}
else if (file_exists($img2))
{
    echo "am here in png";
    $prof_img = $img_name_png;
}
else if (file_exists($img3))
{
    echo "am here in jpeg";
    $prof_img = $img_name_jpeg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
is_bool(file_exists($img1)) == 1
```

Tests whether the outcome of `file_exists()` is a boolean, which it always is.

That said, you can write a small helper function that does the testing for you using an array of extensions you want to look for:

```
function filePathMatchingExtensions($path, array $extensions)
{
    foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
        if (file_exists($path . $extension)) {
            return $path . $extension;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'];
$prof_img = filePathMatchingExtensions("../img/profile_imgs/$user_id", $extensions);

if ($prof_img !== false) {
    // it exists
} else {
    // it doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to keep file name in your database , and not try to guess the extension of the file.
Anyways you can try the @Typoheads reply or function glob() if necessary 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php